# Два A_I в одной таблице mysql

Tags: mysql

К примеру есть таблица со столбиками:

id
user_id
login

Первые два столбцы имеют авто-енкримент. Задача стоит так что бы при вставки новой строки с любым логином id увеличивался на единицу, а user_id увеличивался на единицу только при определенном логине (к примеру есть логин 'user1' то увеличиваем на единицу).

Возможно такое реализовать одним запросом, без предварительного SELECT user_id?

Comment: Тогда второе это не автоинкремент. Сделать, по идее, моно, только я условие не понял. Напишите примерные данные, и что должно получиться после insert

Comment: Нет. А что вам мешает эту логику перенести на ЯП в котором вы формируете запрос?

Comment: Допустим есть запрос в таблице которою я описал выше:
"INSETI NTO users (login)"  VALUES ('user_1')
В таком случаи user_id в добавленной строке должен увеличиться на единицу, если же запрос с любим другим логином то нет.

Comment: ЯП это как, покажите пожалуйста на примере в запросе?

Comment: _а user_id увеличивался на единицу только при определенном логине_ А при другом логине, что должно с ним происходить, оставаться NULL, равняться последнему, который уже был вставлен в таблицу последним ? А если не секрет, зачем вам такая логика, нарушающая третью нормальную форму ?   а ЯП=язык программирования - это не в запросе. Можно конечно триггерами на таблицу попробовать изобразить

Comment: user_id увенчивается только при определенном логине на единицу больше от предыдущей записи с таким же login, для других логином также...

Comment: Это нужно что бы формировать историю пополнения баланса, именно номер каждого пополнения.

Comment: Без предварительного `SELECT` это можно сделать только если поле `login` имеет индекс `UNIQUE`. Имеет?

Comment: Ну можно изменить на UNIQUE, Имеет.

Comment: @Юрий90 А название user_id - это что бы всех запутать ? с таким названием кажется, что это id пользователя (который, кстати, должен быть, вместо самого login). Такое только с select max(user_id) where login='xxx', возможно в триггере. Но такое в 90% случаев не нужно. Где далее будет использоваться этот номер ? Обычно достаточно хранить дату/время операции и можно уже выдавать всю историю в правильном порядке, при желании нумеруя строки уже при выборке

Comment: Нумерация строк помогла бы, но история будет чиститься удерживая только 10 последних записей для каждого login. А задача состоит в том что бы знать номер пополнения для каждого login. user_id это да несколько неправильно, можно deposit_id.

Answer (score 1):

Абсолютно автоматически сделать указанную вами нумерацию невозможно, auto_increment тут не помощник. Надо либо заключать select max(user_id) в триггер. Либо сам insert писать в виде:

```
insert into users(user_id,login)
 select coalesce(max(user_id),0)+1,'login1'
   from users where login='login1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Если поле `login` имеет `UNIQUE` индекс, то можно сделать так

```
$login = 'any_login';
$sqlStr = "INSERT INTO users (user_id, login) VALUES (0, '$login') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user_id=user_id+IF('$login'='user1', 1, 0)";
```

Ну и запустить этот SQL.

`user_id` будет изменяться лишь в том случае, если вставляемый логин `='user1'`.

Comment: Да не уникальный он у него, он же говорил:  
_user_id увенчивается только при определенном логине на единицу больше от предыдущей записи с таким же login_ значит с одним логином у него может быть несколько записей ...